# Scroller not working with bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a piece of code that I have called my "scroller" and it basically switches the user from one button to another and back with arrow buttons. It works fine when I don't use bootstrap but now that I am trying to use bootstrap it wont work. here is the code:

```css
/*START MINE SCROLLER CONTROL*/
#containerms {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 49%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.boxms {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
    left: 150%;
    top: 100px;
    margin-left: -25%;
    
}
#box1ms {
    left: 50%;
}

.movems {
    position:fixed;
    z-index:2;
    top:50%;
    margin-top:-20px;
    text-align:center;
    padding:20px;
    background:#fff;
    color: #000;
}
.leftms {
cursor:pointer;
left:50%;
width: 1px;
height: 1px;
border-radius: 30px;
background: #BABABA;
color: #fff;
clear: both;
display: block;
text-align: center;
font-size: 20px;
line-height: 3px;
}
.rightms {
cursor:pointer;
right:1%;
width: 1px;
height: 1px;
border-radius: 30px;
background: #BABABA;
color: #fff;
clear: both;
display: block;
text-align: center;
font-size: 20px;
line-height: 3px;
}
ul{
    list-style: none;
}

span.namems{
  width: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #ABA38F;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
}
/*END MINE SCROLLER CONTROL*/
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-6" id="green-line-l">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

     <div class="row" style="height:100%;">
      <div class="movems leftms circle" > < </div>
   <div class="movems rightms circle" > > </div>
   <div id="containerms">
    <ul>
     <li id="boxms1" class="boxms current"><span class="namems">Forest Floor</span>
       <br>
       <br>
      <input type="button" id="forestfloor" onclick="mine1Click()"></input>
       <br>
       <br>
     </li>
     <li id="boxms2" class="boxms"><span class="namems">Forest Cave</span>
      <br>
      <input id="forestfloor"></input>
     </li>
     <li id="boxms3" class="boxms"><span class="namems">Cave Atrium</span>
      <br>
      <input id="forestfloor"></input>
     </li>
     <li id="boxms4" class="boxms"><span class="namems">Deep tunnles</span>
      <br>
      <input id="forestfloor"></input>
     </li>
     <li id="boxms5" class="boxms"><span class="namems">The Dark Roads</span>
      <br>
      <input id="forestfloor"></input>
     </li>
     <li id="boxms6" class="boxms"><span class="namems">Abandonded Mine</span>
      <br>
      <input id="forestfloor"></input>
     </li>
     <li id="boxms7" class="boxms"><span class="namems">King's Tomb</span>
      <br>
      <input id="forestfloor"></input>
     </li>
     <li id="boxms8" class="boxms"><span class="namems">Underground Kingdom</span>
      <br>
      <input id="forestfloor"></input>
     </li>
     <li id="boxms9" class="boxms"><span class="namems">Dragons Lair</span>
      <br>
      <input id="forestfloor"></input>
     </li>
     
        
    </ul>
    </div>
    <script>
    debugger
    var i = 1;
   $('.rightms').click(function () {
    if (i < $("#containerms ul li").length) {
     $("#boxms" + i).animate({
      left: '-50%'
     }, 400, function () {
      var $this = $("#boxms" + i);
      $this.css('leftms', '150%')
       .appendTo($('.containerms'));
     });
     $("#boxms" + i).next().animate({
      left: '50%'
     }, 400);
     i++;
    }
   });
   $('.leftms').click(function () {

    if (i > 1) {
     $("#boxms" + i).animate({
      left: '150%'
     }, 400, function () {
      var $this = $("#boxms" + i);
      $this.css('rightms', '-150%')
       .appendTo($('.containerms'));
     });
     $("#boxms" + i).prev().animate({
      left: '50%'
     }, 400);
     i--;
    }
   });
   </script>
  </div>
  
    </div>
   </div>
```

I have no idea what is wrong with this code and am looking for some help. thanks.

Comment: If you are using bootstrap, you can better use  carousel for this

Comment: You should put css in head and js in footer, also, jquery must be loaded first not last. Also your custom code should be called inside an on load window or on ready document function.

Comment: Bootstrap.js requires jquery. You're loading jquery after bootstrap.js. Reverse the order and load jquery before bootstrap.js will fix this for you.

Comment: I changed the load order and it still didn't fix it. As to using a carousel I have tried that and it does not work how I want it to. I don't know what is is meant by and on load window. I am very new to programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so i figured it out. The `row` that contained the "scroller" was not expanding, vertically or horizontally enough to reveal the content, so I manually forced them to expand.